# Prevent UIBarButtonItem in UIKeyboard from complying to UIAppearance

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uikeyboard, uiappearance

I am doing the following to prevent the 'Done' button in the `UIKeyboard` from using the `UIBarButtonItem` appearance, but I wanted to know if there was a better way to do so, as if a user has another `UIToolBar` in his application containing a `UIBarButtonItem`, it will also be affected.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:NSClassFromString(@"UIToolbar"), nil] setTitleTextAttributes:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:NSClassFromString(@"UIToolbar"), nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:NSClassFromString(@"UIToolbar"), nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```